# Numbers of specified length that can be made using individual elements from an array

Tags: c++11

Let's say we have given an array of digits, *A*, and a positive number, *B*. The problem is to generate all the possible *B*-digit numbers combined of *A*'s elements.

For example, if *A* = [0,1,2,3] and *B* = 2, then the output must be,

```
  [10,11,12,13,20,21,22,23,30,31,32,33]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Generate all possible combinations​ of 2 digit numbers by multiplying and adding the elements of the array in nested `for` loops.
- Check if the generated numbers are greater than 10 to be a valid two digit number.

`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

int main () {
    int A[4] = {0,1,2,3}; int B = 2; int k;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]); i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]); j++)
        {
         k = (A[i] * pow(10, B-1) + j); 
         if(k / 10 > 0)
            std::cout << k << '\n';
        }
    }    
}
```